# Scala trait as a method input - type mismatch error

Tags: scala, traits

I wrote a method that gets a trait type as an input.
This is the trait `Localizable`:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate
trait Localizable {
   val location : Coordinate
}
```

This is the method:

```
def localizeWithId(rdd : RDD[Localizable]) : RDD[(BigInt,Localizable)] = {
   return rdd.map { case place =>
     (getIdFromLocation(place.location.x, place.location.y), place)
   }
}
```

The issue is that when I try to call this method, and send a case class that extends this trait as a parameter, I get an error of type mismatch.

This is the case class:

```
case class At (
  eventDate : DateTime,
  location : Coordinate
)  extends Localizable
```

and this is the call:

```
val ats : RDD[At] = ...
val atsLocalized : RDD[(BigInt, At)] = localizeWithId(ats)
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: your problem might be that you annotated expected type as `RDD[(BigInt, At)]` while actual return type is `RDD[(BigInt,Localizable)]` which is type mismatch, exacly what you get. Solution might be to define `def localizeWithId[A <: Localizable](rdd: RDD[A]): RDD[(BigInt, A)]`

Comment: Thanks! that's perfect

Comment: ok, let me post this as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that here:

```
val atsLocalized : RDD[(BigInt, At)] = localizeWithId(ats)
```

you said you expect `RDD[(BigInt, At)]` to be returned, while actual return type is declared as RDD[(BigInt,Localizable)].

`RDD` is invariant so you can't put `RDD[B]` where `RDD[A]` is expected even if `B` would be subtype of `A`. But that is not the case here anyway.

You can make your method generic like this:

```
def localizeWithId[A <: Localizable](rdd: RDD[A]): RDD[(BigInt, A)]
```

requiring `A` to be subtype of your trait.